# Speed up kusama-local onboarding

Tags: parachain, kusama, docker

We are using rococo-local in our CI/CD but we would like to move to kusama-local because we need to test some xTokens pallet ( upwards / downards transfers ) functionalities with Kusama.

We are using `paraSudoWrapper` from the rococo-relay chain to speed up the onboarding of our parachain in our Docker setups but looks like this is not that available for Kusama-based rely chain. Am I missing something? Is there another workaround?

Here an example on how we are registering the chain:
https://github.com/mangata-finance/mangata-node/blob/develop/devops/dockerfiles/parachain-registrator/src/index.js#L61

Thanks!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is another useful feature that no one knows it exists (until now I hope): [fast-runtime](https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot/pull/4332)

So that you can build a Kusama local runtime with reduced session time without waiting hours for onboarding.

```
KSM_EPOCH_DURATION=40 KSM_LAUNCH_PERIOD=3 cargo build --release --features=fast-runtime
```

Comment: O_o will try! Thanks @Bryan!

Comment: Hi @Bryan, 
I have an issue at block #40 when building with those params:
```
2022-03-25 08:34:48 Error with block built on 0xfb0b51206dc4473d1bb7ad71283cc7783885ed1ea0415c7ca82d6c2cc369049a: ClientImport("Expected epoch change to happen at 0xbdda8544c7bbe6b3e506cb3c2443d5fd4d49ed6bc2ca5efec968104d9c39384d, s274698948")    

```
Thanks!

Comment: Running it with:
./target/release/polkadot --alice --validator --rpc-cors=all --tmp --chain=/home/goncer/projects/chainspec_raw_ksm.json --port 30333  --ws-port 9944 > ../alice.txt 2>&1 &
in polkadot v0.16 released version.
With spec:
target/release/polkadot build-spec --chain=kusama-local  --disable-default-bootnode --raw > ../chainspec_raw_ksm.json

Comment: would the issue be that im generating the spec and fast-runtime is not fully compatible with it? 
I think that the spec is almost mandatory to me, otherwise ( if using --chain=kusama-local ) my parachain is not imporing blocks from the relay because of genesis mismatch.
` Reason: Genesis mismatch, Disconnecting`

Comment: they should be compatible. `Expected epoch change to happen at ` usually means your node did not produce a block for too long

Comment: Hi Bryan! 
I made it work without the KSM_ related variables.
I created this, 
https://github.com/mangata-finance/mangata-node/blob/develop/devops/parachain/docker-compose-ksm.yml
By building a node with the feature = fast-runtime and using this script to onboard the chain,
https://github.com/mangata-finance/mangata-node/blob/develop/devops/dockerfiles/parachain-registrator/src/index_ksm.js
Many many thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2):

There is no simple work around, Kusama (as you might know) is a production network where sudo is *not* used. Rococo is *intended* to be the place to test all things before you move to Kusama or Polkadot, thus we should be sure that features you need are included in Rococo. Please open an [issue](https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot/issues) to ask for the things you want to test be included with reasoning why.

For testing things out you *may* find that [try runtime](https://docs.substrate.io/v3/tools/try-runtime) or the [Polkadot emulator](https://github.com/shaunxw/xcm-simulator#xcm-emulator) (or now up-streamed simulator) would be a good place to test things as well.

Comment: Would be technically possible to adapt the onboarding time for kusama-local spec? 
If so I 'll create an issue in Github.
I think is important to make rely-chain testable enough for parachains to be able to deliver quality in the integrations.
And thanks for the answer @dan!

Comment: Thanks for the thanks! An upvote would be nice too to signal this 

Comment: I think this has been suggested before... someone was maintaining a fork for the emulator that "hacked" the block/session times to allow for various changes in reconfiguration to accelerate things, but then it's not a proper test of the runtime that is on Kusama properly.... but I agree opening an issue/PR that suggests `local` only chainspecs with a different onboarding time may be useful. Let's see what the maintainers think?